# How to concat an array within an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, concatenation

Here is the problem. How do I do this below. The array within an array is throwing me off.

> [...] alert to the screen the entire first movie in eightiesMovies, but only using the eightiesMovies variable. For now, use the concatenation operator to unite the words into one string. Remember to be attentive to necessary whitespace [...]
>
> ```
> var movie1 = [ 16, "Candles"];
> var movie2 = [ 3, "Men", "and", "a", "Baby"];
> var eightiesMovies = [ movie1, movie2];
> ```

I have tried these answers to no avail

```
alert(eightiesMovies[0][0].concat("", eightiesMovies[0][1]));
alert(eightiesMovies([0][0]).concat("", eightiesMovies([0][1]));
```

Comment: Post what you've tried and what didn't work - the question looks *copied and pasted*

Comment: http://miwayagi.com/code/2014/05/js-array-adjusting-array-contents-i/ ...

Comment: Are you trying to concatenate all the strings in the array into one string, or are you trying to concatenate the elements of the array into one array?

Comment: It sounds more like you should use `+`, not `.concat`. `.concat` is not an operator. I wonder why you tried `eightiesMovies([0][0])` though. That would try to call `eightiesMovies` as a function. And it clearly is not a function. If you not very familiar with JS' syntax, I recommend to read a tutorial first: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide .

Comment: Thank You for your time gentlemen....feeling silly not using +......I'm new to this, and I always seem to make it more confusing than it really is.

Answer (score 0):

Very simple:

```
movie1.concat(movie2) // will combine the 2 arrays

movie2.join(''); will join the element in the array 

result:
movie2.join('') => "3MenandaBaby"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
eightiesMovies[0][0] + " " + eightiesMovies[0][1]
```

The concatenation *operator* in this case is `+`, [which is used to concatenate strings together](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#String_operators).  Since this is a nested array, you can chain array access.  You want the first movie (which is an array in the first element of the `eightiesMovies` array at position 0).  Then just concatenate each value of that array.  You would have to know the length of the arrays ahead of time.  That is to say the above would only print out *part* of the second movie.